# How to use dot(.) to MongoDB(Mongoose) schema as a parameter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB Data object is here, It use mongoose so has Schema, The Schema name is **Users** :

```
{ 
  id: abcd1234
  level: 1,
  user_name: 'Man'
}
```

I want to make general function that can change database.

```
function editData(key, value){
    Users.findOne({ id : 'abcd1234' }, function(err, user){
        // The problem is below line 
        user.key = value; 

        user.save(....);
    });
}
```

It didn't work. because `user` doesn't has `key` schema. I think Node.js think the 'key' to mongodb schema, not a parameter. How can I use `key` as a parameter?

Comment: You are doing it wrong anyway. Do not  `.findOne()` and `.save(). There is no guarantee the document does not change on the server in the middle of that process. Use [`.findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) instead

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thanks. It works well following document that you noticed.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Maybe I should use findByIdAndUpdate. It just sample code but I didn't know that.